# linux audit repeating USER_ACCT CRED_ACQ LOGIN USER_START USER_END under cron

Tags: cron, linux-audit

my system is Suse SLES 11.4 x86-64 and the following seems to be generated every minute.  This is after a system reboot with much of everything turned off in chkconfig, including auditd.
I start auditd manually and do a `tail -f /var/log/audit.log` and capture the following:

```
node=shark type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1476133081.102:283): user pid=9179 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:accounting acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1476133081.102:284): user pid=9179 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=LOGIN msg=audit(1476133081.102:285): login pid=9179 uid=0 old auid=4294967295 new auid=0 old ses=4294967295 new ses=13
node=shark type=USER_START msg=audit(1476133081.102:286): user pid=9179 uid=0 auid=0 ses=13 msg='op=PAM:session_open acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=CRED_DISP msg=audit(1476133081.766:287): user pid=9179 uid=0 auid=0 ses=13 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=USER_END msg=audit(1476133081.766:288): user pid=9179 uid=0 auid=0 ses=13 msg='op=PAM:session_close acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'


node=shark type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1476133141.766:289): user pid=9372 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:accounting acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1476133141.766:290): user pid=9372 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=LOGIN msg=audit(1476133141.766:291): login pid=9372 uid=0 old auid=4294967295 new auid=0 old ses=4294967295 new ses=14
node=shark type=USER_START msg=audit(1476133141.766:292): user pid=9372 uid=0 auid=0 ses=14 msg='op=PAM:session_open acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=CRED_DISP msg=audit(1476133142.446:293): user pid=9372 uid=0 auid=0 ses=14 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=USER_END msg=audit(1476133142.446:294): user pid=9372 uid=0 auid=0 ses=14 msg='op=PAM:session_close acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'


node=shark type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1476133261.130:307): user pid=9778 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:accounting acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1476133261.130:308): user pid=9778 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=LOGIN msg=audit(1476133261.130:309): login pid=9778 uid=0 old auid=4294967295 new auid=0 old ses=4294967295 new ses=17
node=shark type=USER_START msg=audit(1476133261.130:310): user pid=9778 uid=0 auid=0 ses=17 msg='op=PAM:session_open acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=CRED_DISP msg=audit(1476133261.802:311): user pid=9778 uid=0 auid=0 ses=17 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=USER_END msg=audit(1476133261.802:312): user pid=9778 uid=0 auid=0 ses=17 msg='op=PAM:session_close acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'


node=shark type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1476133321.806:313): user pid=9972 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:accounting acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1476133321.806:314): user pid=9972 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=LOGIN msg=audit(1476133321.806:315): login pid=9972 uid=0 old auid=4294967295 new auid=0 old ses=4294967295 new ses=18
node=shark type=USER_START msg=audit(1476133321.806:316): user pid=9972 uid=0 auid=0 ses=18 msg='op=PAM:session_open acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=CRED_DISP msg=audit(1476133322.474:317): user pid=9972 uid=0 auid=0 ses=18 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=shark type=USER_END msg=audit(1476133322.474:318): user pid=9972 uid=0 auid=0 ses=18 msg='op=PAM:session_close acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
```

**my /etc/audit/audit.rules file is only this**

```
# First rule - delete all
-D

# Increase the buffers to survive stress events.
# Make this bigger for busy systems
-b 8192000

# -f is failure flag, 0=silent, 1=print, 2=panic shutdown
-f 1

# -e is enable context flag, 0=disable, 1=enable, 2=lockdown reboot required
-e 1
```

So far i have found if i turn off **cron** via `/etc/init.d/cron` then it seems to have stopped the repetitive 6 lines of output that was happening every minute.

I have found this article : https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2009-November/msg00000.html
and the posted answer was "This has come up in the past and we don't have a good solution, We have kicked around adding filtering based on selinux context"

Can anyone shed some light on this and what the best course of action is?
Because it amounts to a 100+ MB log file after a week and is no value added.

Comment: i guess the big question is,  can i just disable cron?  Is cron needed, what would be the side effects of `chkconfig cron off`

Comment: i just set up a new system with a fresh install of SLES from dvd, and I can confirm the same 6 entries happening but it is happening every 15 minutes.

Comment: Did you solve this problem yet? I'm having the same problem with CentOS 6 and some Docker containers. As a result I'm having thousands of `CRED_ACQ`, `USER_START`, `USER_END`, `CRED_DISP`, `USER_ACCT`, `LOGIN`, `CRED_REFR`, `NETFILTER_CFG` entries in `audit.log` mostly caused by `crond`.

Comment: haven't messed with it since then, i only remember `chkconfig crond off` being somewhat of a solution.  I was not able to figure out the root cause.